# Create UWP package using cmake

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, uwp, xbox

I'm working on simple hello world application:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

// CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(hello)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
```

I'm trying to build it using:

```
cmake -G "Ninja" "-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=WindowsStore" "-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=10.0"
ninja
```

And it seems to build, but I'd like to additionally generate UWP package (.appx) to be able to deploy it on xbox.

How can I create UWP package with this example, that will be deployable to xbox?

Comment: I'm going to guess building with Visual Studio and not Ninja is probably a good first step.